# Converting key value pair using sed or awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

Looking for sed or awk expression to convert key values to specific format. In this case, there is no value for pass, so it should show an empty string.

Input:

```
login: me pass: time: Wed 2020 07 message: There is a cat in the house
```

Desired output:

```
login="me" pass="" time="Wed 2020 07" message="There is a cat in the house"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything for this?

Comment: tried splitting in python, but does not cover all cases ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
echo "login: me pass: time: Wed 2020 07 message: There is a cat in the house" |
sed -E 'G; s/ [[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*:/\n&/g; s/: ?([^\n]*)\n/="\1"/g'
```

Prints:

```
login="me" pass="" time="Wed 2020 07" message="There is a cat in the house"
```

Notice that this will convert any `key: value` pairs into `key="value"` provided that the `:` character is used only for specifying the `key` and for nothing else.